# How to forward anything@subdomain.domain.com to anything@domain.com

Tags: email, subdomain, email-bounces, crm

### Scenario

Our company has two web servers.  Our main doman, `domain.com` is hosted offsite using a hosting provider (In this case, Netfirms).  One of our subdomains, `subdomain.domain.com` is hosted onsite and is reached via a `CNAME` entry in the DNS records at `domain.com`.  Our e-mail server is hosted at `domain.com` and therefore we can only create `name@domain.com` e-mail addresses.  Our CRM system is hosted on `subdomain.domain.com`, and generates URL links based on `subdomain.domain.com`.  This is useful for generating links in e-mails sent out to contacts, but it is unfortunately also generating `cc` e-mail addresses in the form `name@subdomain.domain.com`.

### Thoughts

We do have a catchall email account setup at `domain.com`, but anything sent to `subdomain.domain.com` is not caught here.  Is this because `domain.com` and `subdomain.domain.com` are at two separate IP addresses, and therefore anything sent to `subdomain.domain.com` looks for a mail server there instead of `domain.com`?

### What can I do?

Do I need to setup a mail server @ `subdomain.domain.com` just to catch these?
Is there someway to redirect mail traffic sent to `subdomain.domain.com` to `domain.com`?

Is this a good scneario for an MX entry in the DNS records?  I'm a bit new to DNS records and how they work.  `HOST` should be set to `subdomain.domain.com`, I imagine and `POINTS_TO` set to `mx.somain.com`, but what about `Priority`?

### --EDIT--

Current MX table at `domain.com`

```
Priority    HOST    POINTS_TO
30          @       mx.domain.com
30          @       mx.domain.com
30          *       mx.domain.com
30          @       mx.domain.com
30          *       mx.domain.com
30          *       mx.domain.com
```

The hosting provider uses `Roundcube` to handle mail.

Comment: What do you use to handle your email?

Comment: and have you created mx records for that sub-domain?  perhaps your mail provider can simply catch those and map them to your existing tld account.

Comment: @MichaelHampton: I just edited the question to include using MX records.

Comment: You haven't answered my question.

Comment: @MichaelHampton That's not important. MX for subdomain should point to host where domain's MTA live. MTA should have subdomain in the local-domains-list. Subdomain should have proper SPF records to allow submission from both domain/MTA and subdomain hosts. Any actual MTA is suitable for that.

Comment: @Kondybas Any actual MTA is suitable for that, but the actual MTA has to be configured for it! Which will be his next question.